# jQuery setInterval update PDO content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

I'm wanting to run a jquery script that updates a content box every so often. I want the contents on this box to be from my database.

So far I have this, which isn't much, but not sure how the best way would be to replace the content. This is how my approach would be, but i'm sure its incorrect and there is a better way, also this does not work anyways.

```
<div id="list"> List here </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function(){ updateList(); }, 8000);
    });
    function updateList(){

    $('#list').html(
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE enable = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
            $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
            $stm->execute();
            $u = $stm->fetchAll();
            foreach ($u as $list) { 
                ?>
                "<?php echo $list['name']; ?>";
                <?php 
            } ?>
        );

    }
</script>
```

My question is, how would I be able to do this? Thanks

Comment: PHP is just a preprocessor. your PHP code is "executed"/parsed once on the server before sending the result page to the client. It will not refresh data whenever your run your JS function. What you might need to do is use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and a dedicated PHP script to do the update.

Comment: @Vivick Thank you for your reply. Would it be possible if you could show how to do this by ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute an Ajax function that call PHP server side operations like this (with `<ul><li>` list to show all elements separeted, but optional) :

**list.php**

```
<?php

    function get_list() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE enable = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
        $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
        $stm->execute();
        return $stm->fetchAll();
    }

    if($_GET['update']) {
        $html = '<ul>';
        foreach(get_list() as $element) {
            $html. = '<li>'.$element['name'].'</li>';
        }
        echo $html . '</ul>';
        die();
    }

?><html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        Some css and js...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="list">

        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function(){ 
                    $.get('list.php?update=1', function(data) {
                        $('#list').html(data);
                    });
                }, 8000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment :

> PHP is just a preprocessor

Therefore I recommend the use of AJAX and a separated PHP script to do the job (and an `<ul>`):

getEnabledsNames.php

```
<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM list WHERE enable = 1 ORDER BY id DESC";
  $stm = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
  $stm->execute();
  $u = $stm->fetchAll();
  $u = array_map(function($elem){
    return $elem['name'];
  }, $u);

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($u);
?>
```

The JS code

```
let interval;
$(document).ready(()=>{
  interval = setInterval(updateFromDb, 8000);
});

function updateFromDb(){
  $.get(
    "getEnabledsNames.php",
    (data)=>{
      $("#list > ul").html("");
      data.forEach(e=>{
        $("#list > ul").append(`<li>${e}</li>`);
      });
    }
  ).fail(/* function to handle failure here */);
}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="list">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
var gtimer;
$(document).ready(function() {
    clearInterval(gtimer);
    gtimer = window.setInterval(function() {
        clearInterval(gtimer);
        updateList();
    },8000);
});
```